# How to prove that $|\mathcal{F}(\Lambda, \Omega)| = \infty$ for a matrix that induces a non-linear system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nonlinear-system

I talked to my advisor about this (twice actually), but I simply do not understand his reasoning unfortunately. Given the following matrix (which is a covariance matrix in the broader context, but I guess that's not important here)
$$
\Sigma = (\sigma_{ij}) = \begin{pmatrix}
\omega_{11} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \omega_{22} & \omega_{23} + \lambda_{23}\omega_{22} \\
0 & \omega_{23} + \lambda_{23}\omega_{22} & \omega_{33} + 2\omega_{23}\lambda_{23} + \lambda_{23}^2\omega_{22}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
I want to show that there is an infinite amount of choices for the entries of $\Lambda$ and / or $\Omega$  such that the (covariance) matrix stays the same, so $|\mathcal{F}(\Lambda, \Omega)| = \infty$, which denotes the fiber of a function that simply maps $(\Lambda, \Omega)$ onto the (covariance) matrix. The entries of $\Lambda$ and $\Omega$ are unknown coefficients. Now he told me something the lines of treating every entry as an equation with $\omega_{22}$ as a free variable but not the other $\omega_{ij}$, so something like

$\begin{equation}
\sigma_{22} = \omega_{22} \\
\sigma_{23} = \omega_{23} + \lambda_{23}\omega_{22} \Leftrightarrow \omega_{23} = \sigma_{23} - \lambda_{23}\omega_{22}\\
\sigma_{33} = \omega_{33} + 2\omega_{23}\lambda_{23} + \lambda_{23}^2\omega_{22} \Leftrightarrow \omega_{33} = \sigma_{33} - 2\omega_{23}\lambda_{23} - \lambda_{23}^2\omega_{22}
\end{equation}$

I don't understand the point of that. If I treat $\omega_{22}$ as a free variable, wouldn't this always yield a different matrix since $\omega_{22}$ stands alone on the diagonal of $\Sigma$?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing your advisor meant to say you *fix* $\omega_{11}=a$ and $\omega_{22}=b$ and then show that the following system has infinitely many solutions:
$$
\begin{cases}
\omega_{23} + \lambda_{23}b = \sigma_{23} \\
\omega_{33} + 2\omega_{23}\lambda_{23} + b^2\lambda_{23}^2 = \sigma_{33}
\end{cases}$$
for given $\sigma_{ij}$ values. In the above two equations, the variables are $\omega_{23}, \lambda_{23}, \omega_{33}$ and so it should have infinitely many solutions because you only have two equations.

Comment: So at the end it's just due to the fact that I have three variables and two equations? Yeah, fixing $\omega_{11}$ and $\omega_{22}$ was his first hint, then he switched it to treating $\omega_{22}$ as a free variable, which doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Why did you write $b^2$ in though? Did you mean?

Comment: $b^2$ is a typo, it should be $b.$ I am sure he mistakenly said $\omega_{22}$ should be a free-variable. Otherwise, it is straightforward to prove that the above system of equations has infinitely many solutions.